# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 at java.util.ArrayList.get

Tags: java, android

AdapterClass:

```
public class AdapterForNamesListInUpcoming extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterForNamesListInUpcoming.SingleItemRowHolder> {

    private List<SingleItemModelForUpcoming> itemsList;
    private List<SingleItemforPhoneNumbers> itemforPhoneNumbers;
    private List<SingleItemForDates> itemsforDates;

    private Context mContext;



    public AdapterForNamesListInUpcoming(Context context,  List<SingleItemforPhoneNumbers> itemforPhoneNumbers , List<SingleItemModelForUpcoming> itemsList,List<SingleItemForDates> itemsforDates) {
        this.itemsList = itemsList;
        this.itemforPhoneNumbers = itemforPhoneNumbers;
        this.mContext = context;
        this.itemsforDates = itemsforDates;




    }







    @Override
    public SingleItemRowHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.upcomingclientlistlayout, null);
        SingleItemRowHolder mh = new SingleItemRowHolder(v);
        return mh;


    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SingleItemRowHolder holder, int i) {

        SingleItemModelForUpcoming singleItem = itemsList.get(i);
        SingleItemforPhoneNumbers singleItemforPhoneNumbers = itemforPhoneNumbers.get(i);
        SingleItemForDates singleItemForDates = itemsforDates.get(i);




        holder.nameofclient.setText(singleItem.getName());

        holder.phoneNumber.setText(singleItemforPhoneNumbers.getPhoneNumber());
        holder.date.setText(singleItemForDates.getObjectDate());



    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (null != itemsList ? itemsList.size() : 0);
    }

    public class SingleItemRowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements 
    View.OnClickListener {

        protected TextView nameofclient , phoneNumber ,date;



        public SingleItemRowHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            this.nameofclient = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nameofclient);
            this.phoneNumber = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.phoneNumber);
            this.date = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.date);



            view.setOnClickListener(this);



        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {





        }

    }

    }
```

SingleItemForDates ObjectClass:

```
 public class SingleItemForDates {

    private String ObjectDate;




    public SingleItemForDates(String ObjectDate) {
        this.ObjectDate = ObjectDate;

    }


    public String getObjectDate() {
        return ObjectDate;
    }

    public void setObjectDate(String objectDate) {
        ObjectDate = objectDate;
    }
}
```

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="550dp"
android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
android:layout_height="150dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
android:paddingBottom="30dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">



<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="560dp"
    android:id="@+id/clientlist"
    android:background="@drawable/upcomingandhistorybackground"
    android:layout_height="100dp">



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="2:30"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/gothic"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


<View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:background="#fff"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nameofclient"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Name"
    android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:fontFamily="@font/gothic"
    android:textSize="20dp"/>


    <!--Not in use-->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/phoneNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:text="rr"
        android:fontFamily="@font/gothic"
        android:textSize="20dp"/>



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="date"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:fontFamily="@font/gothic"
        android:textSize="20dp"/>

    <!--Not in use-->


    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="495dp"
    android:src="@drawable/rightarrow"/>
```

I am getting the following error while trying to get the date from the class. Any help would be appreciated.

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.get at   at UpcomimgPages.RecyclerViewForUpcomng.AdapterForNamesListInUpcoming.onBindViewHolder(AdapterForNamesListInUpcoming.java:63)
        at UpcomimgPages.RecyclerViewForUpcomng.AdapterForNamesListInUpcoming.onBindViewHolder(AdapterForNamesListInUpcoming.java:19)
```

Comment: post your activity code

Comment: Which is the line 63 of your adapter? It seems `itemsList` looks good, but I'm almost sure that your error is happening between `itemforPhoneNumbers.get(i);` or `itemsforDates.get(i);` since you are passing `i` adapter position on both as argument and probably they don't have the same number of elements as `itemsList` has.

Comment: SingleItemForDates singleItemForDates = itemsforDates.get(i);   This is the line where error is showing @JulioLemus

Comment: It is in the question already the XML @kam1234

Comment: @AyeshaIsrar `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 at java.util.ArrayList.get` means `itemsforDates.get(i);` has no items and you are trying to get an item trough `i` position, in this case `Index: 0`. Make sure that `itemsforDates` has the same number of items as`itemsList.size();` and that will fix it.

Comment: Be careful there, you have next 3 lists, `itemsList.get(i);`, `itemforPhoneNumbers.get(i);`and `itemsforDates.get(i);`

You are passing the same `i` position as argument, so, once you pass them trough the `AdapterForNamesListInUpcoming`'s constructor you must to make sure all have the same size `.size()` to avoid a similar error in the future.

Answer (score 1):

**What's happening:** `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 at java.util.ArrayList.get` means that `itemsforDates.get(i);` has no items and you are trying to get an item from there trough `i` position, in this case `Index: 0`.

**To fixt it:** Make sure that `itemsforDates` has the same number of items than `asitemsList.size();` and that will fix it.

**Suggestion:** Be careful there, you have next 3 lists: `itemsList.get(i);`, `itemforPhoneNumbers.get(i);` and `itemsforDates.get(i);` and you are passing the same `i` position as argument, so, once you pass them trough the `AdapterForNamesListInUpcoming`'s constructor, you must to make sure all lists have the same size `.size()` to avoid a similar error in the future.